# Pandas - changing each date in a date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(You can assume the date column is datetime)

This may be relevant to the problem, but I also have a list of dates with the following values:

```
['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', 
'2018-04-01', '2018-05-01']
```

I have the following table:

```
date         arb1      arb2      amount
2018-01-02   Z         F         5
2018-01-03   G         H         10
2018-02-04   V         T         51
2018-03-03   R         S         54
```

I want this output, where each date has been set to the first of its corresponding month:

```
date         arb1      arb2      amount
2018-01-01   Z         F         5
2018-01-01   G         H         10
2018-02-01   V         T         51
2018-03-01   R         S         54
```

**Bonus (not required):** What I'm actually trying to do is add up the amounts after grouping by date (the month), arb1, and arb2, and the final output has each date as the first of the month. I figured an easy way to get here would be to first change each date to the first of the month, but if there is an easy way to do this in pandas then the above steps aren't required and you can skip to this instead

Comment: Interesting task. What have you tried so far? Can you provide a **[mcve]** of the problem you face?

Comment: Did you know reading Pandas documentations helps in answering 90% of questions? Pandas has awesome documentation that is way to good to not read it. This question could be answered by reading this section:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex

Comment: @jpp the other question you linked doesn't deal with the case of one of the dates already being the first of a month

Comment: @JesusMonroe, See the second dupe. It has the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need below to get the first date of the month.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
```

Output:

```
        date arb1 arb2  amount
0 2018-02-01    Z    F       5
1 2018-01-01    G    H      10
2 2018-02-01    V    T      51
3 2018-03-01    R    S      54
```

Comment: Can't believe it's always so simple. Thanks

Comment: This actually doesn't work perfectly. I had a value that was 2018-02-01 and this method changed it to 2018-01-01

Comment: @JesusMonroe Edited. Let me know how this one goes.

Comment: Oh I figured it out but this is way cleaner anyway. For posterity I also got it with: df['date'] = np.where(~df.date.isin(months), df.date - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), df['date'])